# Vis timeline add custom button inside item

Tags: vis.js, vis.js-timeline

It's my first time working with Vis timeline and I have a [Timeline](http://jsfiddle.net/e7uodse2/1066/)

```
var data = new vis.DataSet([{
    id: 1,
    content: 'First event',
    start: '2014-08-01'
}, {
    id: 2,
    content: 'Pi and Mash',
    start: '2014-08-08'
}, {
    id: 3,
    content: 'Wikimania',
    start: '2014-08-08',
    end: '2014-08-10'
}, {
    id: 4,
    content: 'Item 4',
    start: '2014-08-20'
}, {
    id: 5,
    content: 'Summer bank holiday',
    start: '2014-08-25'
}]);
```

I don't know if is possible or not but does vis timeline support adding custom button in the right side inside items like item 4 (for example) that only displays a message on click?

Comment: Yes, you can put anything (valid html) in there. Vis also supports using a template function to provide the 'content' – but if you need only one link, you probably don't need to go that far.

Comment: You are right! I managed to add an image to my item :)  Thanks! :)